# Is there a world generator that can create a Minecraft world that is solid rock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

**Is there a world generator that can create a Minecraft world that's solid rock?** Literally, with one layer of bedrock at the bottom and the other 127 layers stone?

I don't care if it generates ores or not since it will be hosted on my server with other normal worlds connecting to it, but it would be a HUGE pain to make a world like that with [mcedit](http://davidvierra.com/mcedit.html) or other programs manually.

It would be a huge plus if there's a bukkit plugin that can do that too. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite the contrary, it seems really easy to do with MCEdit (I've just tried it).

- Start MCEdit, create a new world. Put in a few numbers - how large a world do you want to have?
- Once the world is generated, press `ctrl + a`. That selects the whole world.
- Select the `Fill` tool. Pick `stone` and pres `fill`.
- Similarly, fill the bottommost layer with `bedrock`. (set the selection height to `1`.
- Take care to place the spawn point wherever you like it.

Save, and you're ready to go.

Comment: I believe ctrl-a only selects all chunks in MCEdit's current working area, but I could be wrong. Does doing this allow walking infinitely far in-game and still getting only flat stone?

Answer (score 8):

World generation now comes with a powerful [preset tool](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Superflat#Preset_code_format). The code for generating one layer of bedrock followed by 127 layers of stone is:

```
2;7,127x1;1
```

Comment: Compared to the MCEdit option, his has the added benefit of still working no matter how far off the "edges" of the map you go.

Comment: Thats better ^ ^

Answer (score 3):

You can download a [flat stone world.](http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/flat-stone-world/)  Just extract to the same location as your other worlds.

Comment: I needed a solid stone (bedrock to max height) world. =)

Comment: @KortPleco I think you mean bedrock to a few less than max height.  Otherwise, there would be no room for players.  :)

Comment: @KortPleco You said bedrock on the bottom layer and the rest stone.

Comment: @John I think he meant the stone should be "from bedrock to max height".

Comment: @ver Then there would be no place for players.  The world would be solid stone with no air for players to exist in.

Comment: @John I thought that was the point. Let them spawn in some 2 cubic meters and let them dig. But I admit I'm not sure - I've never seen anyone play such a world.

Comment: @ver Even in that case, I would imagine that would require at least 2 blocks being air not stone, so not *totally* stone, but I've never played a world like that either.  If it were me, I would make the spawn room a moderate sized empty space underneath the surface layer.

Comment: @John: Players can exist above the map. I think the spawn-point can be placed at max height and the players would spawn half in stone, one jump and they're out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, however, I'm quite surprised nobody has mentioned the CleanroomGenerator plugin (http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/cleanroomgenerator/files/6-v1-0-0/). Along with a world management plugin (I use Multiverse), you can create worlds with any combination of layers.